# overfull hbox too wide in Figure

Tags: graphics, captions, subcaption, overleaf, sidewaysfigure

I am using this method to add 3 images as a single figure in a column such that each image appears in a different row and there's nothing else in the row. The overall figure should be in center. However, currently it's towards the left of the screen and it is starting from almost the middle of the screen instead of starting from the top (eg first line). How can I fix this? I

Currently, I get the overfull hbox too wide in paragraph error on all 3 \includegraphics lines. What might be causing it? I have looked through similar solutions but nothing seems to work.

```
\begin{figure}
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=1.5\linewidth]{standard.png}
  \caption{1a}
  \label{fig:sfig1}
\end{subfigure}%
 \newline
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=1.5\linewidth]{depthwise.png}
  \caption{1b}
  \label{fig:sfig2}
\end{subfigure}
 \newline
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=1.5\linewidth]{Pointwise.png}
  \caption{1b}
  \label{fig:sfig2}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{plots of....}
\label{fig:fig}
\end{figure}
```

I added \newline to ensure that each fig comes on the next line.

Comment: it is far more efficient to use a blank line rather than use `\newline` (which forces text to consider all of the figures as a single paragraph and run its line breaking algorithm to finally end up with one per line.)

Comment: I tried following the answer given below but it doesn't seem to work for me. Could you maybe take a look here? overleaf.com/5329187891vxqmmwsfgngr @DavidCarlisle

Comment: did you get a chance to go through the link @DavidCarlisle

Answer (score 2):

The overfull `\hbox` comes from [width=1.5\linewidth].  Inside figure `\parskip=0pt` so use `\par` (blank line) instead of `\newline`.  I added the [height=4cm] simply to get the example images to fit on the page.

If you remove the `\topfraction` definition, it will move to the next page.

```
\documentclass[letter]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{showframe}% MWE only

\def\topfraction{0.9}

\begin{document}
 \begin{figure}
\centering% in case you want to use a narrower subfigure
\begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.75\linewidth, height=4cm]{example-image-a}
  \caption{1a}
  \label{fig:sfig1}
\end{subfigure}%

\begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.75\linewidth, height=4cm]{example-image-b}
  \caption{1b}
  \label{fig:sfig2}
\end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.75\linewidth, height=4cm]{example-image-c}
  \caption{1b}
  \label{fig:sfig2}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{plots of....}
\label{fig:fig}
\end{figure}

Some text to be on top of.
\end{document}
```

Comment: If I try your code, the alignment is fine but the height of images is smaller than desired. When I increase the height to for eg 1.5, all images move down again.  It is starting from almost the middle of the screen instead of starting from the top (eg first line). However, if I only change the height of the first image, then it's starting from the top

Comment: I create a demo here https://www.overleaf.com/5329187891vxqmmwsfgngr

Comment: There is a limit on how large a [t] float can be (default is `\def\topfraction{0.7}`).  Exceed that and it will become a [p] float.

Comment: Sorry, I am still not being able to comprehend how I can fix this

Comment: did you get a chance to go through the link ?

Comment: To access that link, I would have to log on to overleaf.  I do not have, not want, an overleaf account.